# Select column only if factor levels over 1 by group column value

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am running over thousand binomial models using purrr on a species presence dataset (presence/absence 1/0).

As I get the Error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I want only include columns in the model where the factor level is > 1.

But: For this I need the factor level for the respective presence values (1/0)

This only works for combined presence factor levels.

```
grp  |pres | V1 | V2 |V3
grp1 |0    |10  |9   |10
grp1 |0    |9   |9   |10
grp1 |1    |8   |7   |10
grp1 |1    |5   |9   |10
...
grp2 |0    |10  |7   |8
```

The dataset is grouped and nested by the grp column.

My code drops column V3, but not column V2, because the combined factor levels for pres = 1 & 2 is 2. 
This aborts the model calculation.

```
library(tidyverse)

nested %>% 
    mutate(glm = map(.f = function(x) { 

    y <- x %>%
        mutate_all(factor) %>%
        droplevels(., except = c(1,2)) %>%
        select_if(function(col) all(col == .$pres) | nlevels(droplevels(col)) > 1) %>% 
      mutate_all(as.ordered)

      glm(pres ~ ., data = y, family = binomial(), na.action = "na.fail")

    }, .x = .$data))
```

I cannot reproduce a (failing) working dataset, but the Error only comes up where one of the predictor columns only has 1 level.

Comment: Yes, I actually used that, but I don't want to return something else, I just want to exclude the column with factor levels < 1 from model calculation.

Comment: Maybe you could filter out groups with only 1 value of factors prior to nesting/model fitting?  This may even work after nesting; it would help to have an example dataset for testing.